# mp android (line chart) Iaxisvalue formatter causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

my app works fine but as soon as i added the iaxisvalue formatter teh app crashes and returns a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1 and im lost and cant find a proper solution of how to solve it using kotlin

this is my activity fragment, and when it comes to the chart im trying to format the x axis values to string values :

```
    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter =
                IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis ->
                    if (xAxis[value.toInt()] == 0) "12 AM" 
                    else if (xAxis[value.toInt()] < 12) "${xAxis[value.toInt()]} AM" 
                    else if (xAxis[value.toInt()] == 12) "12 PM" 
                    else "${xAxis[value.toInt()] - 12} PM"
                }
```

like the above but it returns the above error after it crosses 12AM

and here is the activity fragment in which the chart is used,the following function fetched the chart data for daily data, and the xaxis values too, here im trying to display time on the xaxis.

```
 private fun fillTodayData() {
        chart.invalidate()
        try {
            if (todayData.size < 1) {
                chart.visibility = View.GONE
                xAxisLabel.visibility = View.GONE
                return
            } else {
                chart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                xAxisLabel.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            val LineEntries = ArrayList<Entry>()
            //val LineEntries: MutableList<Entry> = ArrayList()
            val dataObjects = todayData
            val xAxis = mutableListOf<Int>()
            var i = 0
            for (step in dataObjects) {
                // turn your data into Entry objects
                if (step.value > 0) {
                    LineEntries.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), step.value.toFloat()))
                    Log.d(
                        LOG_TAG,
                        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgraph entries $LineEntries \n$step"
                    )
                    xAxis.add(step.key)
                    i++
                }
            }
            val vl = LineDataSet(LineEntries, "My Type")
            //Part4
            //setting color for the line graph and the gradient
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.yellowBar)
            vl.setColor(color)
            vl.setDrawFilled(true)
            if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
                // fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above
                val drawable: Drawable? =
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.gradient_background)
                vl.setFillDrawable(drawable)
            } else {
                vl.setFillColor(Color.BLACK)
            }
            vl.setDrawValues(true)
            vl.lineWidth = 1f
            chart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 0f
            val lineData = LineData(vl)
            lineData.isHighlightEnabled = true //marker for each point
            lineData.setValueFormatter { value, _, _, _ ->
                if (value > 0) {
                    "$value"
                } else {
                    ""
                }
            }
            chart.data = lineData
            val graphSize: Int = if (LineEntries.size > 8) 8 else LineEntries.size
//
            chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(graphSize.toFloat())
            chart.moveViewToX(0F)
////
            chart.xAxis.labelCount = graphSize
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "today $dataObjects \n$xAxis")

            println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + xAxis)
            println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + graphSize)
            chart.xAxis.valueFormatter =
                IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis ->
                    if (xAxis[value.toInt()] == 0) "12 AM" else if (xAxis[value.toInt()]
                        < 12
                    ) "${xAxis[value.toInt()]} AM" else if (xAxis[value.toInt()] == 12) "12 PM" else
                        "${xAxis[value.toInt()] - 12} PM"
                }

            chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
            chart.invalidate()
//Part8
            chart.setTouchEnabled(true)
            chart.setPinchZoom(true)
            chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
//Part9
            chart.description.text = ""

//Part10
            chart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)

//Part11
            val markerView = CustomMarker(context!!, R.layout.marker_view)
            chart.marker = markerView
            chart.isScaleXEnabled = false
            chart.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
            chart.setScaleEnabled(false)
            dataLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fillTodayData() Exception $e")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Labels are not guaranteed to be drawn exactly where there are actual data points. E.g. a label could be drawn further to the left of your lowest x value. This is most probably what happens in your example, because the exception says it wants to get the value at index -1, so 1 to the left of you lowest x value 0.

But your approach does not support this. I see the following possiblilities for you to fix this:

1. Interpolate/Extrapolate the values.

   - E.g. for the x value -1 you probably want to show "11 PM" (last day).
   - It would also be possible that MpAndroidChart wants to display a label at 5.5 for example (if you zoom into the chart). You could display 5:30 AM in that case.
   - By setting `chart.xAxis.granularity = 1f` you can prevent MpAndroidChart from labelling x values like 5.5.
2. Do not display labels at all which do not correspond to an actual data point. In your ValueFormatter you could just return an empty String for those cases. I would recommend to use this only in combination with `chart.xAxis.granularity = 1f`.